Why am I getting a bad request error when trying to create a folder in SharePoint via API?
I am trying to create a Sharepoint folder in my C# app, and keep getting a 400 Bad Request response. My code seems to match the examples I find online. What am I doing wrong?
public async Task CreateFolder(string folderName, MainWindow uiWindow)
{
    string accessToken = null;
    using (var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager())
    {
        accessToken = await authenticationManager.GetAccessToken(uiWindow);
    }
 
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        var folderData = new
        {
            __metadata = new { type = "SP.Folder" },
            ServerRelativeUrl = $"{_site}/{folderName}"
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folderData);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync($"{_site}/_api/web/folders", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Folder created successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        }
    }
}


There are several thing that could go wrong when trying to perform an operation against a API.
First of all I'd suggest you use Bruno (Postman or whatever) to send the request manually before trying to implement it in Code.

Verify that your obtained bearer token is valid and has the permission to create and list folders. My first guess is that something is wrong here. But as said before this can be easily tested by checking your bearer token manually in a tool like Postman.
Verify that you use the correct headers in general:
Taken from the MS Docs

POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/folders
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
Content-Type: "application/json"
Content-Length: {length of request body as integer}
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Folder"
  },
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/document library relative url/folder name"
}

As you can see the accept header is different it's application/json;odata=verbose. Sometimes this can make a difference with strongly typed APIs. So I suggest that you verify your bearer token first and afterwards try to modify your code to the following:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json;odata=verbose"));

Microsoft documentation for reference Working with folders and files with REST

@MatthewHagemann I faced similar issue in the past when the folder name contains unallowed characters. such as "*:<>?/\|.
Can you send us sample of the folder/s names?
